# Using one column to update values in another column

Tags: excel, vlookup, formulas

I have Column A (let's call this `Column A - Names`) with 1,000 rows of values. Column D has 50 values - let's call this one `Column D - Names` - which reside somewhere scattered throughout `Column A - Names`.

The `Column A - Names` column has significantly more values than `Column D - Names`.

Column B and Column C have values that correspond to `Column A - Names` and `Column D - Names`, respectively, which we'll call `Column B - Birthdays` and `Column C - Birthdays`.

Is there a way to use `Column D - Names` to reduce `Column A - Names` (from 1,000 down to these 50)?

If so, then, after that, update `Column B - Birthdays` to be the values of the **correct** `Column C - Birthdays`?

Here is a visual of the problem:

```
v(Wrong)v    v(Wrong)v    v(Right)v    v(Right)v

Column  A |  Column  B |  Column  C |  Column  D
  Names   |  Birthdays |  Birthdays |    Names
-----------------------------------------------
   Tom    |  01/01/72  |  10/19/73  |    Joe    
   Joe    |  05/21/76  |  08/27/65  |   Craig    
  Harry   |  09/23/63  |  11/30/66  |    Tom    
  Jane    |  02/17/78  |  03/02/82  |   Martin    
   Amy    |  12/09/81  |  07/14/77  |    Kim    
   ...    |  ........  |  ........  |    ...
```

### Summary

In summary, both `Column A - Names` and `Column D - Names` contain names with corresponding birthday values in `Column B - Birthdays` and `Column C - Birthdays`, where `Column D - Names` & `Column C - Birthdays` contain the **correct** values and `Column A - Names` & `Column B - Birthdays` contain the ***incorrect*** values. I only want to update the 50 names in `Column D - Names` from the massive list of 1,000 names in `Column A - Names`.

Comment: Why not add illustration then with sample data? You can add a photo to your post.

Comment: You will not be able to do this in place without vba.  Formulas are live and therefor you can have a formula or you can have a value but not both.